# jQuery mobile menu toggle not closing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

I'm having an issue trying to close my mobile menu with jQuery. It opens fine and changes the attribute of the element as intended but doesn't fire on the second click, so everything after the else doesn't seem to happen.

The only thing I found that may be of consideration is that jQuery only remembers the state of attributes on load? (Not sure if this is correct) My theory is that if it checks the visibility of a loaded object that is false and on click the data-visible is changed to true it only remembers the object as false & doesn't execute the else on second click?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var primaryNav = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
  var navToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-nav-toggle');

  $(navToggle).on('click', (function() {
    var visibility = $(primaryNav).data('visible');
    if (visibility = true) {
      $(primaryNav).attr("data-visible", true);
      $(navToggle).attr("aria-expanded", true);
    } else {
      $(primaryNav).attr("data-visible", false);
      $(navToggle).attr("aria-expanded", false);
    }
  }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="mobile-nav nav gradient">
  <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="header" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Menu</span></button>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('inverted-custom-logo') ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav class="header">
      <?php 
        $args = array('theme_location' => 'header');                            
        wp_nav_menu('header');               
      ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can just use the `toggle()` method to alternate the display state of an element. In addition you don't need to use the `data` attribute to store the state of the element, you can just read it from the DOM using the `:visible` selector.

Also note that you're using an odd mix of native JS and jQuery. If you've loaded jQuery in to the page, you may as well use it and make your life easier.

Here's a working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $primaryNav = $('.header');
  let $navToggle = $('.mobile-nav-toggle');
  
  $navToggle.on('click', () => {
    $primaryNav.toggle();
    $navToggle.attr("aria-expanded", $primaryNav.is(':visible'));
  });
});
```

```css
.header { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="mobile-nav nav gradient">
  <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="header" aria-expanded="false" type="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
  </button>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('inverted-custom-logo') ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav class="header">
      Menu content here...
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. It no longer animates though because the data-visible was controlling the CSS translate from -100 to 0 with 

.header[data-visible="true"] {
        transform: translateX(0%);
}

Comment: As well as the navigation is stuck to display:none; when resizing so when resizing to a larger screen size the navigation is no longer visible.

EDIT: I fixed this by adding a min-width media query and a .header{display:block!important;} the display:none is within the max-width media query